# Discord bot command bug

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Please help me id why this doesn't work:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    const channel = message.channel
    const members = channel.members
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "muteall")) {
        message.guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type == "voice").forEach((voicechannel) => {

              voicechannel.members.forEach((x) => {
                member.voice.setMute(true)
                member.voice.setDeaf(true)
              });

            });
            return message.channel.send("Svi su mutovani!")
}
  });
  client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "unmuteall")) {
        message.guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type == "voice").forEach((voicechannel) => {

              voicechannel.members.forEach((x) => {
                member.voice.setMute(false)
                member.voice.setDeaf(false)
              });

            });
            return message.channel.send("Svi su unmutovani!")
}
  });
```

The bot works but after the unmute command is called it crashes and gives this error:

```
Cannot read property 'setMute' of undefined
```

Comment: `(x) =>` states that each element in the iterable will be labled as `x`, yet you try to use `member`

Answer (score 2):

In your `forEach` callback, you are naming the member `x`, but attempting to access `member`.

You need to replace `(x) => {` with `(member) => {`